# ng-model-options depending on $dirty flag?

Tags: angularjs

I want to create an email field which validates on blur, but if the user has changed it, it should update after one second. The use case is that the user comes back to the email field to correct the email address. Then the validation should be done quicker.

I have tried something like this:

```
<input type="email" class="form-control" ng-model="field.value" ng-required="field.required" ng-model-options="{ updateOn: 'default blur', debounce: {'default': ($dirty ? 1000 : 10000), 'blur': 0} }">
```

but it doesn't work. It will always give me 10s debounce for default.

Answer (score 2):

The ngModelOptions attribute probably gets evaluated only once so the $dirty flag is always false.

Comment: This does seem to be the case.